Packaged Self-Contained WinUI3 Application Not Responding for 5 minutes after MSIX install
I have a packaged self-contained WinUI3 project using MSIX tooling. After going through Package and Publish > Create App Packages on my project, and installing with the resulting MSIX executable, the application launches and immediately is unresponsive. Clicking on the application brings up the not responding dialog, but after waiting 5 to 10 minutes, however, the application functions as normal. The unresponsive behavior continues for each subsequent launch of the application.
When debugging the application in VS 2022, there is no delay when launching the application. Does anyone have any ideas on where to look/change to figure out what is causing this issue?
Project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <RootNamespace>AppName</RootNamespace>
        <ApplicationIcon>Assets/app-icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
        <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
        <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>True</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
        <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
        <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
        <PublishProfile>Properties\PublishProfiles\win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
        <PackageCertificateThumbprint>omitted</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
        <AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>SHA256</AppxPackageSigningTimestampDigestAlgorithm>
        <GenerateAppInstallerFile>False</GenerateAppInstallerFile>
        <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
        <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>False</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
        <AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>False</AppxSymbolPackageEnabled>
        <GenerateTestArtifacts>True</GenerateTestArtifacts>
        <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
        <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Animations" Version="7.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls" Version="7.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.5.240428000" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed" Version="2.0.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="WinUIEx" Version="2.3.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Publishing profile:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Platform>x86</Platform>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishDir>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(RuntimeIdentifier)\publish\</PublishDir>
    <SelfContained>True</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishReadyToRun Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">True</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Windows App SDK Version: 1.5.240428000

I suggest you could try to run it on another device and whether you could experience the same issue?
